# What is causing my PHP file to display the code, instead of executing it?

Tags: php

I know a lot of you guys are going to get angry, because it seems like so many questions have been based on this alone!

But, I have checked my PHP tags, all of which are using `<?php...`, PHPMyAdmin is installed on my server.

I just don't understand what's causing this? T_T

- ftp://ftp.wagermatches.net/public_html/arithia/referral/test/home.php

I've tried changing the URL from ftp:// to...

- http://ftp.wagermatches.net...
- http://www.wagermatches.net...
- http://www.wagermatches.net/arithia/referal...

I tried adding a .htaccess file to my server...

I'll be getting into my server classes two months from not, but I have no clue what's wrong. If you've got any idea, could you please point me to tutorials on how to do something and not just what I need to do? I am still learning. :( Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: Causing what? All I see is a bunch of URLs. Did you know that Stack Overflow is a repository of programming questions, like a FAQ? It is not a helpdesk/forum. Those links are unique to you and will also die one day, so they are off-topic here.

Comment: Maybe ... http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the file through FTP will not cause it to be interpreted. Instead, you will get the file literally as you are now.

If you wish the file to be interpreted, you must first [access it through HTTP](http://www.wagermatches.net/arithia/referral/test/home.php) and then configure your server to interpret it. How to do that depends on the web server you are using. As is, you’re getting an internal server error, which means that something is wrong with your server’s configuration. A good first step to diagnosing the problem would be to check the error log, as the internal server error page says.

Comment: Thanks. I contacted my host, and they resolved the issue. I guess I'll learn more about this in the upcoming months. Thank you for taking the time to help out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not recognizing the php tags, so I think you do not have PHP installed. Note: I am not talking about PHPMyAdmin !!!